# Prevent to show default windows context menu in winEvent in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to to get word under mouse cursor but when user right click in any window, default windows context menu appear, how can i prevent showing default windows context menu in winEvent in Qt?

```
bool EventReceiverWindow::winEvent (MSG *message,long *result )
{

    if( message->message == WM_RBUTTONUP ) {
            // *result = ?  (What's value should i passed to *result to prevent showing defualt context menu)
              return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this windows explorer? Or do you want to disable context menu on all Windows programs?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: You answered "yes" to an either or question

Comment: @David Heffernan: I want to disable context menu on all windows programs.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass TRUE to the *result and return true;

```
bool EventReceiverWindow::winEvent (MSG *message,long *result )
{

     if( message->message == WM_RBUTTONUP ) {
          *result = true;
          return true;
       }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are attempting to do is not practical. You'd need to hook into the message queue of all running apps. That's just not a realistic proposition. I can't guess what's driving this question but I wonder if a system wide hot key might serve your needs.